# memory management xcode 4.4

Tags: memory-management, instruments, xcode4.4

Today I installed the new Mountain Lion and with it the new Xcode 4.4, so I imported the new project I had just started on the new
xcode, and I realized that after I log in, because my app requires a login with username and password, log in I get a warning
"low memory", then it made ​​me suspicious, and I analyzed Instruments and I noticed that when you open the app already part of almost 2MB alocazione complessiava
Then if I start to edit text field in each letter I write up at least 0.5 MB which is impossible, I have strange things in my app and there is nothing that works
If you have not be logged.
I do not use ARC.
It could be that I imported from xcode 4.3 to 4.4 and is not 100% compatible?
I have to do something when the amount?
validate the setting is ok.